# delete first N bytes from a text file

Tags: logging, go

Is there any function call or simple way to delete first N bytes from a text file in golang? Assuming that the file is contentiously appended by various go-routines, simultaneously I want to delete first N bytes of file.

Comment: There's no way to do that in any language, because that's not how files work. Also, writing to a file concurrently is usually not a good idea, since writes may be interleaved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `f.Seek` to jump over first bytes and than do regular reading, see example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])            // open file from argument
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var skipBytes int64 = 5                  // how many bytes to skip

    _, err = f.Seek(skipBytes, io.SeekStart) // skipping first bytes
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)               // allocating buffer to read
    for {
        n, err := f.Read(buffer)               // reading
        fmt.Print(string(buffer[:n]))          // writing to console
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Err: %v\n", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution

Comment: @Vicky if this solutions resolves your question, please, mark answer as accepted. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used following approach but it moves whole file content not the N bytes.

data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(srcFilePath) // Read all content of src to data
_ = ioutil.WriteFile(destFilePath, data, 0777) // Write data to dst
errTrunc := os.Truncate(srcFilePath, 0)   //To empty the file